# how to multi-check react-native-element's checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a newbie with React Native, I'm building a quiz application with multiple choices by using "react-native-elements" to generate the checkboxes. But I don't know how to control the multi-check function. I have searched and found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43867821/how-to-render-multi-components-and-set-individual-status-in-react-native/47025846#47025846).

But I still don't understand that when using Michael Peyer solution, which is the state I should define on the constructor function to adapt this solution?

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = ??;
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

This follows the basic principles of RN and handling an array inside state. What I checked the **react-native-elements** docs, it should work as is. Although there may be some room for improvement, but start with this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    checkboxes: [{
      id: 1,
      title: 'one',
      checked: false,
    }, {
      id: 2,
      title: 'two',
      checked: false,
    }],
  };
}

...

toggleCheckbox(id) {
  const changedCheckbox = this.state.checkboxes.find((cb) => cb.id === id);

  changedCheckbox.checked = !changedChecbox.checked;

  const checkboxes = Object.assign({}, this.state.checkboxes, changedCheckbox);

  this.setState({ checkboxes });
}

...

render ()
  return (
    this.state.checkboxes.map((cb) => {
      return (
        <Checkbox
          key={cb.id}
          title={cb.title}
          checked={cb.checked}
          onPress={() => this.toggleCheckbox(cb.id)} />
      )
    })
  )
```

Comment: Best online example for how to use checkbox in RN.

Comment: Here is the toggleCheckbox worked in my app:                                                            `toggleCheckbox(id) {
        let changedCheckbox = this.state.checkboxes.find((cb) => cb.id === id);

        changedCheckbox._checked = !changedCheckbox._checked;
        let chkboxes = this.state.checkboxes;
        for (let i=0; i < chkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (chkboxes[i].id === id) {
                chkboxes.splice(i, 1, changedCheckbox);
            };
        };

        this.setState({
            checkboxes: chkboxes,
        });
     }`

Answer (score 1):

Try examining this:

```
import { CheckBox, View } from 'react-native'

class QuizScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // this is the default state on page load
    this.state = {
      checkbox1: false,
      checkbox2: false,
      checkbox3: false,
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View> ... etc
        <CheckBox
          value={this.state.checkbox1}
          onChange={() => this.setState({ checkbox1: !this.state.checkbox1 })}
        />

        <CheckBox
          value={this.state.checkbox2}
          onChange={() => this.setState({ checkbox2: !this.state.checkbox2 })}
        />

        <CheckBox
          value={this.state.checkbox3}
          onChange={() => this.setState({ checkbox3: !this.state.checkbox3 })}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

What is going on?

1. the default state is set in the constructor
2. the value `this.state.checkbox1` is the current value
3. `this.setState({ prop: 'value' })` refers to props from your constructor
4. `this.setState({ checkbox1: !this.state.checkbox1 })` sets the value to the opposite of what it's currently set to

The problem in the question you linked is that the person had:

```
this.state = { checked: false }
```

but he/she has multiple checkboxes, so they are all editing the same property on the state object.

Notice how my example has 3 properties on the state object. The other answer by `zvona` in here is very illustrative for handling multiple.