# Problems with creating checkboxes with React Native - TypeError: hashtags.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created some checkbox'es in React Native. That should be hashtags that users can select or deselect. I get error: 'TypeError: hashtags.map is not a function...' when I click on hashtag box but I cant figure out what is the problem. 
I lead myself with those example [how to multi-check react-native-element's checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025910/how-to-multi-check-react-native-elements-checkbox)

Here is my code:

Hashtags.js file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';
const HashtagsList =[
  {checked: false, title: '#tip1'},
  {checked: false, title: '#tip2'},
  {checked: false, title: '#tip3'},
  {checked: false, title: '#tip4'},
  {checked: false, title: '#tip5'},
  {checked: false, title: '#tip6'}, 
];

const Hashtags = props => { 
  const [hashtags, setHastags] = useState(HashtagsList);

const toggleCheckbox = (title) =>{   
  const checkedHashtags = hashtags.find((hashtag) => hashtag.title === title);
  checkedHashtags.checked = !checkedHashtags.checked;
  let checkboxes = hashtags;
  for (let i=0; i<checkboxes; i++)
  {
    if(checkboxes[i].title === title){
      checkboxes.splice(i, 1, checkedHashtags);
    };
  };  
  setHastags({ checkboxes });
}
return(
  hashtags.map((hashtag, i) => {
    console.log(hashtag);
    return (
      <CheckBox
        key = {i}
        title = {hashtag.title}
        checkedIcon={<Image style={styles.chekBoxPic} source={require('../assets/svg/checked.svg')} />}
        uncheckedIcon={<Image style={styles.chekBoxPic} source={require('../assets/svg/unchecked.svg')} />}        
        checked={hashtag.checked}
        onPress={() => toggleCheckbox(hashtag.title)}
      /> 
    ) 
  } )
)

};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({   
  chekBoxPic:{
    width: 22, 
    height: 22, 
  },
});
export default Hashtags;
```

and my App.js file:

```
 <View type={styles.SomeStyle}>
   <Hashtags />
  </View>
```

What I did wrong in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything breaks when you do

```js
setHashtags({ checkboxes });
```

This line is causing `hashtags` to be an object instead of an array. You simply need to remove the curly braces.

```js
setHashtags(checkboxes);
```

Comment: oh God... Thank you so much lol! I hope that this code will work!

Comment: I suppose it worked, would you mind accepting my answer if it helped you?