# How to implement multi-select dropdown with checkbox in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a multi-select dropdown with a checkbox in React Native. Like the below example of Angular Material Component. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBjRw.png), Can anyone suggest the UI component library for it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library you can use for multi select checkboxes [react-native-select-multiple](https://github.com/tableflip/react-native-select-multiple#readme)

For custom implementation, you can go to [multi-check-react-native-elements-checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025910/how-to-multi-check-react-native-elements-checkbox)